# how to convert curl command into php script

Tags: php, curl

I have a situation where i want to use `curl` functionality to get data by `api` call.

> the `curl` command i'm interested to convert look like this:

```
"curl -X POST \\ \n'http://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/getPaymentResponse?merchantKey=40747T&merchantTransactionIds=396132-58876806' \\ \n -H 'authorization: KpNTiy57L6OFjS2D3TqPod8+6nfGmRVwVMi5t9jR4NU= \\ \n -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \\ \""
```

I have tried this much

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/getPaymentResponse');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$array('merchantKey'=>40747,'merchantTransactionIds'=>396132-58876806)) 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

please help me to correct above code!

thank in advance

Comment: The above command `curl -X POST \\ \n'http://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/getPaymentResponse?merchantKey=40747T&merchantTransactionIds=396132-58876806' \\ \n -H 'authorization: KpNTiy57L6OFjS2D3TqPod8+6nfGmRVwVMi5t9jR4NU= \\ \n -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \\ \"` is working fine?

Comment: What is the error in the PHP code?

Comment: https://www.getpostman.com/ . Import from curl, then get generated code for php.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon in your code and you don't need to declare the array as a variable.

```
curl_setopt($ch,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array('merchantKey'=>40747, 'merchantTransactionIds'=>396132-58876806));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this, here i am assuming all your parameters are correct. You were missing some required parameter which were sending in `curl command` but not in PHP curl that is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and `CURLOPT_HEADER` and you should use `http_build_query` while sending array in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` and You should use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` because your current is URL is redirecting from `HTTP` to `HTTPS`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/getPaymentResponse?merchantKey=40747T&merchantTransactionIds=396132-58876806");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('merchantKey'=>"40747",'merchantTransactionIds'=>"396132-58876806")));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('cache-control: no-cache',
                                            'authorization: KpNTiy57L6OFjS2D3TqPod8+6nfGmRVwVMi5t9jR4NU='));
curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP Code

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://test.payumoney.com/payment/op/getPaymentResponse');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    // Add authorization header
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'authorization: KpNTiy57L6OFjS2D3TqPod8+6nfGmRVwVMi5t9jR4NU=',
    ));

    // Remove $ from array()
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('merchantKey'=>40747, 'merchantTransactionIds'=>396132-58876806)) 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // For No-Cache
    curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, TRUE); 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```